# How can I transfer data between spreadsheets using vlookup if spreadsheet changes each month? Can I set it to auto-update?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

[image]

I have the above data in two spreadsheets.

- I receive the top rows. (raw data)
- Then total them using formulas. (middle rows)
- Then need to move them into a separate spreadsheet. (bottom rows,
  `desired result`)

But the 1st spreadsheet changes every month. Can I do this with vlookups?
I'm currently manually copying as the formatting is so tricky, but I'm sure there must be a better way!

Thanks

Hannah

Comment: If you just need to move or copy data that you have calculated in the first spreadsheet, it's easy. For example, click in the cell where you want Season Ticket to be and type an equal sign. Then navigate to the first spreadsheet and click the cell with the Season Ticket number. Excel will fill in the pathname to the first spreadsheet. Similarly, to calculate the sum shown to the right of Staff Costs, type an equal sign and then click on each of the costs, typing a plus sign between each one.

Comment: My findings are, 1. Your Data Sets are not identical. Like in Raw Data, Net Pay is 6th Column and Basic Pay at 9th. But for calculated range Basic Pay is 1st and Net pay is 12th, and many. 2. In this situation Lookup Formula will not work. 3. Even the copy & Paste Link with fail. My suggestion is make the Data sets IDENTICAL!!